# Del operator in one-dimensional domain.

Tags: calculus, vectors, differential-operators

**Question Summary:** If the del operator returns a vector, why when he is applied to a function with one-dimensional domain it returns a scalar function?

---

About the $\nabla$ operator, one can read in Wikipedia (Link [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del))

> Del, or nabla, is an operator used in mathematics, in particular, in vector calculus, as a vector differential operator, usually represented by the nabla symbol $\nabla$. When applied to a function defined on a one-dimensional domain, it denotes its standard derivative as defined in calculus.

There is something here that i don't quite understand. The operator is defined as follows: $$\vec{\nabla} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \vec{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\vec{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\vec{k}$$
In the one-dimensional domain, one could expect:
$$\vec{\nabla} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\vec{i}$$
And here is the problem. This is a *vector*. If i apply the operator to some $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, why it will (according to Wikipedia) return the standard derivative (scalar) and not a vector?

Comment: If the entire problem is in one dimension, the unit vector is completely superfluous.

Comment: So, one dimensional vectors are... scalars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reals are a vector space over themselves so you can consider any real number to be both a vector and a scalar. Since every real $x$ can be represented as $x\times 1$ it follows that $\{1\}=\{\vec{e_1}\}=\{ \vec{i}\}$ is a basis for the reals.

Then $\vec{\nabla} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\times 1 = \frac{d}{d x}$ which is to say that the gradient corresponds to ordinary differentiation.

So to answer your question, $\vec{\nabla}$ is taking a function and giving you a vector back, but for the reals, there is no distinction between vectors and scalars.